# Cambiar imagen de ImageView incluido en CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview

Quiero que el usuario de mi aplicación pueda cambiar la imagen del `ImageView` incluido en el `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, bien obteniéndola a través de la cámara o bien desde una archivo de la memoria interna. Por ahora sólo intento probar cambiándola desde un fragmento en el `onCreateView` mediante `SetImageResource(R.drawable.koala)` y me da error al cargar la aplicación e iniciar ese fragmento. En la `Activity` inflo el `layout` que contiene appBar y demás. En el fragmento inflo un `fragment` que lo incluyo en el `mainactivity.xml`.

así en **`OnCreateView()`**

```
final ImageView imagen_Appbar = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_appbar);
imagen_Appbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.koala);
```

mi **layout toolbar**

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="46dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="44dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="12dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                android:id="@+id/image_appbar"
                android:background="@color/deep_green_700_alpha_50"
                android:minHeight="190dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cielo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

                />

             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

este layout lo incluyo a través de otro raiz con **`CoordinatorLayout`**

```
>
<!-- incluir Toolbar -->
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        >
    <!-- Layout real de la actividad -->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom" android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

he utilizado **Glide** y **Picasso** y tampoco funciona

Comment: No puedes acceder de esa manera a una vista que se encuentre en un layout de un Activity desde un Fragment.
Instancia la vista en el Activity y comunícate desde el Fragment (puedes usar un listener) con el Activity para cambiar la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Es raro que se quiera cambiar la imagen en este tipo de elementos dentro de un `CoordinatorLayout`, veo que tratas de cargarlo desde el `OnCreateView()`, trata esperando un poco con un `handler`:

```
private static final int DELAY = 500;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final ImageView imagen_Appbar = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_appbar);
                imagen_Appbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.koala);
            }
        }, DELAY);
```

También puedes realizar lo mismo con `Picasso` ó `Glide`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No me ha funcionado, sigue fallando.